# Is there any sandbox for stackoverflow APi?

Tags: testing

Did anyone ever met links to StackOverflow sandbox for their own API?
I have found couple of questions which were made for testing answers( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox) , but no way to test questions.

Comment: It will be proper to post this Question in http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! Also did that!

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that there is no such thing as sandbox for stackoverlow API. Just make a test question/answer, mark them properly and then delete.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be really the only way out for now.

Comment: Yes, that is quite unusual thing not to have a sandbox at such a big project.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to be working the way you described.

Comment: hello. this is test api

Comment: hello. this is test api

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will be asearching for sandbox. You can do as mentioned above and then delete the question. You can also make api for the answer and make similar for question (they are not that much different). The same qnswer was received at meta.

Answer (score 0):

That is awesome! I reallyy hope that will work and I  would be able to test. Also, probably anyone can use this answer as testing one. Any way, that's just an offer!